# Sine transform of $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{e^{\sqrt{2 \pi} x}-1} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} x}$

Tags: improper-integrals, integral-transforms

Quoted from Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*:

--

*Now it is known that the function $$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{e^{\sqrt{2 \pi} x}-1} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} x}$$ is self-reciprocal for sine transform, i.e. that $$f(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^{\infty} f(y) \sin (xy) dy.$$*

--

I attempted to prove this but I failed: First I studied the subject from lecture notes available online which included only simple examples like $e^{-\pi x^2}$ but the methods are not practical for this $f(x)$. Then I searched some books to learn more but none helps neither. I asked the question in many different forms on Wolfram Alpha to get a hint but neither full solution nor a single hint I could get from the site.

How the claim of the book holds? A simple clear explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141460/use-rectangular-contour-to-integrate-int-0-infty-frac-sinaxe2-pi-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to perform the integration directly would've been most prudent, at least to me, since one in particular is a famous known integral.

Note that you have to calculate
$$
\sqrt{ \frac 2 \pi } \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{2\pi} y} - 1} \sin(xy) \, \mathrm{d}y
- 
\frac 1 \pi \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y} \sin(xy) \, \mathrm{d}y
$$
The latter is easy to calculate with the obvious substitution and knowing that
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin z}{z} \, \mathrm{d} z = \frac \pi 2
$$
as proved, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-mathrm-dx-frac-pi).

The former integral seems more difficult, but most likely can be found via the same ideas as the simpler integral,
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(z)}{e^z - 1} \, \mathrm{d}z = \frac \pi 2 \coth(\pi) - \frac 1 2
$$
as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324996/a-curious-integral).